# Understanding Application.routes.draw source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

A couple of months ago I started developing web apps with Rails. As with any new framework I use, as a step to further understanding it I’ve started to read the source code. Maybe it’s my relative recent learning of Ruby, but I’m having some troubles making sense of it.

Today I decided to look into `Application.routes.draw` (from `routes.rb`) and from the [ActionDispatch::Routing documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) I found the `draw` method defined in [rails/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb) but I fail to see where in `Application.rb` (or `Engine.rb` or `Railtie.rb`) it comes into play. Additionally I don’t see where the `routes` method in `Application` is defined.

Any answer or link greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the `routes` method in [engine.rb, line #488](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L488). I’ll take it from there.